# Opencart - Test VQmod XML file - What's wrong here?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

just getting used to using VQMod.

What is wrong here? It isn't updating on the front-end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>VQMOD CORE FOR OPENCART - DO NOT REMOVE</id>
    <version>1.4.x and above</version>
    <vqmver required="true">2.5.0</vqmver>
    <author>vqmod.com</author>
   <file name="admin/view/template/common/footer.tpl">
       <operation info="Example of the vQmod">
           <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
           <?php echo $affiliate; ?>
           ]]></search>
           <add><![CDATA[
           I am replaced content!!
           ]]></add>
       </operation>
   </file>
</modification>
```

Cheers!

Comment: the thing you're searching for doesn't exist.  look at your vqmod log to learn about why the xml is failing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are trying to change the "backend" but with no luck!

I think you should read:

- **vQmod**: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki
- **Examples**: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Examples
- **Scripting**: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Scripting

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following, in this file footer.tpl

**admin/view/template/common/footer.tpl**

This is the content:

```
</div>
<div id="footer"><?php echo $text_footer; ?></div>
</body></html>
```

And your script want to find this  "echo $affiliate;" but this content don't exist in this file.

I don't know what file you want to use, but this file don't has this content
**admin/view/template/common/footer.tpl**

Regards,
Miguel